# Send a string to another python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, ipc

I need to send strings to a separate thread asynchronously (meaning no one knows when). I am using `threading` because my problem is IO bound.

My current best bet is [set a flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) and have the receiver thread poll that. When it detects a set flag it reads from some [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

This sounds horribly complicated. Can't I send messages via a [mailbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing)? Or something even better like implicit variable semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue.Queue` class is ideal for this.  Your thread can either block waiting for input, or it can check whether anything new has arrived, and it is thread-safe.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to this or a [pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe). Could you _please_ argue why a queue is superior? Perhaps pipes don't block?

Comment: Pipes are based on sockets.  You just send a byte or character stream.  That means if you're sending objects, you have to serialize them, and deserialize on the other end.  With a queue, you can send Python objects without encoding and decoding.

Comment: Last nitpick would be [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) or [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)?

Comment: For threads, it doesn't really matter.  If you're ever going to go to separate processes, then you'd want `multiprocessing.Queue`.