# How to pass a const queue to a function?

Tags: python, multithreading, constants

I am a C guy. I am aware python [denounces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291791/why-no-const-in-python) the `const` keyword in favour of "we are grownups, we trust each other".

Now I need to inform some python threads of some messages and [decided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70131842/send-a-string-to-another-python-thread) to use a queue. The messages are strings of length up to 1024 characters. I find it absurd that those threads can change those messages for the calling thread or even for themselves.

How can that be prevented? Or is it already?

Comment: In some cases I create a (deep) copy of such messages before sending. Especially when there is a danger that several ends of the system would modify the same data object and thus get unwanted side effects. But let's say, this happens once in 20,000 LoC. But you need to keep an eye on it ...

Comment: What are the messages? Python has quite a few means of immutability, with all primitive builtins being immutable, some containers like tuples, namedtuples and frozensets being immutable, and several utilities like ``dataclass`` offering frozen types. But ultimately if you don't want something changed, don't change it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this sounds far cleaner than a deep copy. I have updated the question that messages are short strings. It's a chat application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Convert your data to one of the immutable types, or create a frozen type. Primitive data such as numbers and strings are always immutable.

---

Python offers several ways of constructing immutable or quasi-immutable values.

- Primitives like numbers, strings and similar are always immutable.
- Containers offer some immutable types, such as [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) or [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) as immutable sequence or set.
- Custom types can be defined as immutable, for example using [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) or [frozen `dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances).

Ideally, data intended to be shared should directly be constructed using immutable types. When this is not possible, *convert* the data from mutable to immutable type before sharing.

```py
>>> # strings are always immutable
>>> data = "Hello World!"
>>> data[:5] = "Howdy"
....
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
>>> # sequence are mutable or immutable
>>> data = ["Hello", "World"]
>>> idata = tuple(data)  # create immutable from mutable sequence
>>> data[0] = "Howdy"
>>> idata[0] = "Howdy"
...
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> data, idata
(['Howdy', 'World'], ('Hello', 'World'))
```